# python import another python script not working

Tags: python

I have two `python` scripts which are in the same directory(`C:\\Users\\user1\\general`). I want to execute a function in one script from the 2nd second script and so I am trying to import `script1` in `script2`. Here is my `script2`:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:\\Users\\user1\\general')
import script1
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecret'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('message')
def handleMessage(msg):
    print('Message: ' + msg)
    # script1 has function called api_call(id,message)
    messsage = api_call('user1', msg)
    send(messsage, broadcast=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

Here is my `script1`:

```
import sys

def api_call(Id,message):
    # Code processing


if __name__ == '__main__':

    uId = sys.argv[0]
    message = sys.argv[1]
    api_call(userId,message)
```

When I execute above `script2` I get `NameError: name 'api_call' is not defined`. It seems somehow the `script1` is not getting imported and so the function is not getting through.

**Note**: Earlier I had tried without using `sys.path.insert()` and same outcome then also.

Comment: did you try `from script1 import *`?

Comment: Or changing `api_call` in `script2` to `script1.api_call`?

Comment: @saniales that's a very bad practice.

Comment: yes, it was just to understand if it was an import problem, clearly the correct solution would be to import only what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `from script1 import api_call`: this would allow to import from `script1` module the `api_call` function.

Answer (score -1):

## Python 2

Create `__init__.py` in the same folder.

Import using following command

`from script1 import api_call`

---

## Python 3

Import using following command

`from .script1 import api_call`

Comment: This syntax (`from .module import ...`) refers to relative import from submodules. It should be used **within packages**, and does not seems an appropriate solution. Same thing for `__init__.py`, a repertory containing this file will be recognized as a package, which is not necessary, and probably not desired here.