# Maya: Python script works in some scenes, but not in others

Tags: python, maya, pymel

I can find one other place where this problem is specifically addressed, but it seems to be even more personal in nature and [the other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46228644/python-import-another-python-script-not-working) provided no help. This is the error:

```html
# Error: Maya command error
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 1, in <module>
#   File "<maya console>", line 26, in createJoints
# RuntimeError: Maya command error #
```

And here is the code, to create a chain of joints along a premade curve:

```html
import maya.cmds as mc

##UI##

jointCurve = mc.window(title = "Create Joint Chain") #window title#
mc.rowColumnLayout(nc = 2) #divides window into two columns#
mc.text(l = "Number of Joints") #dialog prompt#
jntAmount = mc.intField (v = 5, min = 2) #default value of 5, minimum value of 2 joints#
mc.button(l = "Create", w = 150, c = "createJoints()") #confirms entry#
mc.button(l = "Cancel", w = 150, c = "mc.deleteUI(jointCurve)") #closes window, deletes UI#
mc.showWindow() #now that all parameters are defined, the window is opened#

##Method##

def createJoints():
    #Gathering Information#
    selCurve = mc.ls(sl = True) [0]
    jointAmount = mc.intField(jntAmount, q = True, v = True)
    prevJnt = ""
    rootJnt = ""
    
    for i in range(0, jointAmount): #for each increment from 0 to the amount defined in the field,#
        mc.select(cl = True) #clear the selection,#
        newJnt = mc.joint() #create a joint,#
        motionPath = mc.pathAnimation(newJnt, c = selCurve, fractionMode = True) #affix to curve using a motion path,#
        mc.cutKey(motionPath + ".u", time = ()) #remove animation keys from joint's U value (position on curve),#
        mc.setAttr(motionPath + ".u", i * (1.0/(jointAmount - 1))) #distribute joints evenly along curve#
        #delete motion path#
        mc.delete(newJnt + ".tx", icn = True)#deletes x translate value's input connections#
        mc.delete(newJnt + ".ty", icn = True)#deletes y translate value's input connections#
        mc.delete(newJnt + ".tz", icn = True)#deletes z translate value's input connections#
        mc.delete(motionPath) #deletes motion path itself#
        
        if i == 0:
            prevJnt = newJnt
            rootJnt = newJnt
            continue #skips next instructions for root joint since it has no parent#
        
        mc.parent(newJnt, prevJnt) #parents current joint to previous joint#
        prevJnt = newJnt #sets status of "previous" joint to current joint#
    mc.joint(rootJnt, e = True, oj = "xyz", sao = "yup", ch = True, zso = True) #orients joints along chain#
    mc.deleteUI(jointCurve) #closes prompt window#
```

Whenever I run the code in a new file, it works perfectly, no issues.

But I have another file that, when I run this code, it throws the above error.

So it looks like it's having a problem somewhere with importing Maya commands?
as well as with this line, in particular:

```html
mc.cutKey(motionPath + ".u", time = ())
```

For some reason, this error is thrown even when I start a new file, and *import* the other file into the scene.

I have absolutely no idea where to start looking..

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your ui which is prior to the creation of your command

```
import maya.cmds as mc
from functools import partial

##Method##

def createJoints(*args):
    #Gathering Information#
    selCurve = mc.ls(sl = True) [0]
    jointAmount = mc.intField(jntAmount, q = True, v = True)
    prevJnt = ""
    rootJnt = ""
    
    for i in range(0, jointAmount): #for each increment from 0 to the amount defined in the field,#
        mc.select(cl = True) #clear the selection,#
        newJnt = mc.joint() #create a joint,#
        motionPath = mc.pathAnimation(newJnt, c = selCurve, fractionMode = True) #affix to curve using a motion path,#
        mc.cutKey(motionPath + ".u", time = ()) #remove animation keys from joint's U value (position on curve),#
        mc.setAttr(motionPath + ".u", i * (1.0/(jointAmount - 1))) #distribute joints evenly along curve#
        #delete motion path#
        mc.delete(newJnt + ".tx", icn = True)#deletes x translate value's input connections#
        mc.delete(newJnt + ".ty", icn = True)#deletes y translate value's input connections#
        mc.delete(newJnt + ".tz", icn = True)#deletes z translate value's input connections#
        mc.delete(motionPath) #deletes motion path itself#
        
        if i == 0:
            prevJnt = newJnt
            rootJnt = newJnt
            continue #skips next instructions for root joint since it has no parent#
        
        mc.parent(newJnt, prevJnt) #parents current joint to previous joint#
        prevJnt = newJnt #sets status of "previous" joint to current joint#
    mc.joint(rootJnt, e = True, oj = "xyz", sao = "yup", ch = True, zso = True) #orients joints along chain#
    mc.deleteUI(jointCurve) #closes prompt window#


def cancelUI(jointCurve, *args):
    mc.deleteUI(jointCurve)
    
##UI##

jointCurve = mc.window(title = "Create Joint Chain") #window title#
mc.rowColumnLayout(nc = 2) #divides window into two columns#
mc.text(l = "Number of Joints") #dialog prompt#
jntAmount = mc.intField (v = 5, min = 2) #default value of 5, minimum value of 2 joints#
mc.button(l = "Create", w = 150, c = createJoints) #confirms entry#
mc.button(l = "Cancel", w = 150, c = partial(cancelUI, jointCurve)) #closes window, deletes UI#
mc.showWindow() #now that all parameters are defined, the window is opened#
```